# How to display a button when there's a click inside of an iframe

Tags: button, iframe, display

I have an iframe with a form field and a submit button inside the iframe.
How can I display a button below the iframe when I click on the submit button inside the iframe ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you, you want to display a button that is not inside the iframe, right?

In this case try this:

```
$(function(){
    var f=$('#foo')
    f.load(function(){ 
        f.contents().find("#element").on('click', function(event) { 
            newfunction();
        });
    })
})
function newfunction() {
    $("#button").show();
}
```

The #element is the submit button inside the iframe.

The #button is the button you want to display below the iframe. Just change the IDs to your own IDs.